# How can you be immune to damage from bed explosions in the nether/end?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, everyone seems to able to use beds for mining or killing the Ender Dragon, but whenever I use it I blow up instantly.

Is this a bug, or how can I be immune to this damage?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to survive, you are supposed to **place a block in front of the bed and click it as far away as possible (around 5 blocks)**, without being positioned right beside the block in front of the bed. This is so the block will take the main explosive damage of the bed, not the player. Additionally, try to use a block with high blast resistance, such as obsidian, as it will absorb more damage than a block such as wood. A bed explosion in the Nether or  the End is the second most powerful explosion possible. It is as powerful as a charged creeper (which does 97 damage points on normal mode) and is much more powerful than TNT.

*Source: I have done many experiments on this.*

Comment: also, if you have obsidian, it's the best block to use

Comment: @Federico Thanks for clarifying that. I added that into my answer.

Comment: Note that bed explosion (in the Nether or The End) is the second most powerful, with a power level of 6 that is on par with a charged creeper, and is even more powerful than a TNT.

Comment: Note that for using beds to kill the dragon, one method (one cycling) uses the bedrock of the dragon's nest to protect against the damage. This does way more damage to the dragon (upward of 1/4 of its health sometimes), and almost none to the player, because the bedrock absorbs all of the damage.

Comment: Probably the most important point is that the player's hitbox that can receive explosion damage is very small and located at player's feet. If your feet are well shielded from the explosion, you're safe.

Comment: From the speedruns I saw, it's perfectly fine to be directly behind the block.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Calculation_of_explosion_exposure):

Damage depends on "exposure" of your whole bounding box, not just feet. The best result I obtained is placing stone + stone stairs (on top) and activating bed from a quater of a block hole created by stairs. tried with some more blast resistant materials, but with no improvement.